# Autmatic update-search + download + start?

Tags: .net

I have a DotNet Application, a little tool.
I devliver it as a "exe"-file, no installation, no DLLs.

I will now have a automatic update-search (Timer?!), if and update is found, the exe should be closed and the new one should be downloaded and start.

How to do?

Develope a second tool that assist the first tool, or is there an addin / addon / plugin allready developed for such things?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to think about using [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx). It can check for updates, download and install the update for you. You can also create your own event to fire off an update (like from a menu item).

**EDIT**

This will make an installer for your application, but it is pretty lightweight.